# Can I builld a stand alone frontend app with Vue?

Tags: api, react, angular, rest, vue.js

I want to build an API Rest and I want the frontend to be totally independent from the backend, the frontend will comunicate with the backend using an API, sending GET and POST requests, that way I can change the backend, let's say, from Laravel to Django if needed without having to rewrite the frontend. Now I never made a frontend standalone thing ever. I have some knowledge of Vue, integrating Vue with  Laravel and stuff, but never made something totally independent.

So, can I make something like that with Vue? there is any frontend framework you can recommend me to learn for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with Vue (Angular, Emerald, JQuery, plain JS, etc). It is quite standard (in fact, I don't know of any other way :-).

Comment: As mawg says, sure no problem.  I'll add that you don't even need JS to do it - consume the API using PHP, Perl, etc. on a server and generate pure HTML.  sure, you loose the "single page app" feel by using real posts/gets that reload the page, but no client side scripting is required.